# How do I know whether an argument with default value got an explicit one?

Tags: ruby, default

I have a method with arguments that have a default value. I need to know if the value comes from the user or it is a default value. The user can send the default value too. How do I know where the values comes from?

Comment: Interesting question but conceptually dubious. What's the use case?

Comment: i need to know either the user inserted some value in the input area or just clicked the submit button.

Comment: @tokland: There are some standard protocols, e.g. in `Enumerable` which require you to know whether an optional argument was supplied or not. The standard implementations are written in C, Java, C# etc. with privileged access to the interpreter internals, so for them it's trivial. But if you want to re-implement them in Ruby, you have to work around the fact that the Ruby standard protocols require arity-based overloading of methods, but the Ruby language doesn't support it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the trick proposed by Nobu Nakada back in 2004:

```
def some_method( a=(implicit_value=true; 1) )
    puts "a=#{a}; was set #{ implicit_value ? :im : :ex }plicitly"
end

> some_method
a=1; was set implicitly

> some_method 1
a=1; was set explicitly

> some_method 2
a=2; was set explicitly
```

Comment: ugly but smart (or viceversa, not sure)

Comment: The following also works: `def some_method( a=(implicit_value = 1) ) ... end`  (removed the `true;`)

Answer (score 4):

This will also work and looks a little less ugly:

```
def my_method(a = implicit = 1)
  p a
  p implicit
end

# when calling without parameters then a = implicit = 1 is run, hence implicit is assigned a value 
> my_method
1
1

# when calling with a parameter then a = 1 statement is run. implicit will become nil here
> my_method 1 
1
nil
```

Comment: +1 I agree, it's less ugly, which translates to easier to maintain. It'd still need some 'splainin' in the source code though.